# Using AJAX to pass javascript array to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a simple javascript array variable, and I want to pass that array to a CI controller function using jQuery Ajax.

Unlike the many questions on this subject, the array does not originate from a form, and it's not any kind of dom element. I hope this question is not identical to anything else that's been asked on SO. Here's my js code:

```
function processImagesList(){
  var files = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  $("#thumbs li").each(function() {
     var source = $('img', this).attr('src');
     var f = source.split("/");
     var file = f[f.length - 1];
     files[i] = file;
     i++;    
  });
  if(files.length > 0){
    url = "/ajax/add_images_to_asset/";
    var formData = JSON.stringify( files );
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data : formData,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $.each(data,function(k,v){ alert(k + " = " + v); });
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        alert( "Error: " + jqXHR.status + " , " + jqXHR.responseText );
    });
  }
}
```

This basically reads the src of the img tag within an li item, and parses the src string to strip out the relative url of the image, then derive the pure filename of the image.

Next, I store the filename in an array called "files".

Next, I want to pass this array to my CI controller using Ajax.

I've tried `var formData = JSON.stringify( files );`.
I've tried `var formData = $( files ).serialize();`.
I've tried `var formData = $( files ).serializeArray();`.
I've tried sending as method: 'POST';
I've tried sending as method: 'GET';

Here's my controller code:

```
public function add_images_to_asset()
{
    $data = array();
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        //$data["$k"] = $v;
        echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br>";
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Obviously I'm trying to echo out the POST (or even GET) data before the JSON header, but that's ok. No matter what I use, there doesn't seem to be any data (no data makes it to the CI controller function, no matter whether I use the POST or the GET method in Ajax & controller).

The URI is: `console/read_pictures_table`

Comment: Do you mind posting the route for this request, just in case?

Comment: the source of images are correct? or exist images there?

Comment: are you sure ajax sending data ? in which format ajax is sending data ?

Comment: @IanGabes, I posted the uri. No third segment needed. `console/read_pictures_table` @bicho: Yes, the image filenames are fine. I can alert them out, and they are correctly named in the files array.
@user1048123: No, I am not sure the ajax is sending data. But now, thanks to @charlietfl, it is fixed, and sends the data. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending key/value pairs in your data ... only a value which is the stringified array. With no key assigned $_POST will be empty

There is really no need to stringifiy the array either. jQuery will convert to form encoded array internally

Try

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data : {files: files},
    dataType: "json"
})......
```

Then in controller:

```
$files = $this->input->post('files');
// OR
$files = $_POST['files'];
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. That did it. The difference between: ``data : {files: files} and `data: files` in the Ajax side, and `foreach($_POST` and `foreach($_POST['files']` on the controller side. I should know this already, but wasn't thinking straight.